# creating an error to match nom::IResult in nom 6.2.1

Tags: rust, nom

In nom 5.0 this compiles fine:

```
fn escaped_space(i: &str) -> nom::IResult<&str, &str> {
    nom::combinator::value(" ", nom::bytes::complete::tag("040"))(i)
}
assert_eq!(escaped_space(" "), Err(nom::Err::Error((" ", nom::error::ErrorKind::Tag))));
```

but in the current version, 6.2.1 the assert line doesn't compile with a mismatched types error [E0308]:

```
expected Result<(&str, &str), nom::Err<nom::error::Error<&str>>> 

found Result<_, nom::Err<(&str, nom::error::ErrorKind)>>
```

How can I create the error so that it now matches the top one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In nom 6, there is an [additional struct](https://docs.rs/nom/6.2.1/nom/error/struct.Error.html) that contains the error details, instead of the tuple in nom 5:

```
Err( 
    nom::Err::Error(
        nom::error::Error::new( //the new struct, instead of the tuple
            " ",
            nom::error::ErrorKind::Tag
        )
    )
)
```